# Vuejs custom properties on root element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

While developing my app I have had a wrapper (simplified for this example) which is the root of all my elements in the site.  However I needed to include a component with custom properties alongside this wrapper.  That's when I found that the properties on that component were never being read in.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="app" >  <!-- Vuejs is bound to this element -->
    <test-item testProp="My Test Prop Outside Wrapper"></test-item>
    <wrapper></wrapper>
  </div>
</body>
```

**TestItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ testProp }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    testProp: {
      type: String,
      default: "Default String"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Wrapper.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <test-item testProp="My Test Prop Inside Wrapper"></test-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

For reference where I import these components and init the Vue instance:

```
Vue.component('test-item', require('./components/TestItem.vue'));
Vue.component('wrapper', require('./components/Wrapper.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

I would have expected since I am passing in **testProp** on both  instances that the output would look like

```
<h1>My Test Prop Outside Wrapper</h1>
<div>
  <h1>My Test Prop Inside Wrapper</h1>
</div>
```

However, this is not what I am seeing, on the one outside the wrapper, the property is not passed through and the default property value is used

```
<h1>Default String</h1>
<div>
  <h1>My Test Prop Inside Wrapper</h1>
</div>
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Props on element must be written in kebab-case https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case
So component attribute should be `test-prop="value here"`

Comment: @BelminBedak how I didn't notice that I have no idea.  Thankyou very much.  Can you stick this up as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML attributes are case-sensitive so when you want to send prop, the atrribute of prop should be written in kebab-case instead of camelCase.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

In your case, something like this:

```
<test-item test-prop="My Test Prop Inside Wrapper"></test-item>
```